# display last processed time of ssas cube on excel

Tags: olap-cube

I have an analysis cube built in BIDS 2010. The latest Financial Year partition of Cube will be refreshed every 15 mins and so the users need a datetime stamp to be displayed on excel displaying the last time the Cube partition was refreshed.

Its not a duplicate of [Get SSAS cube last process time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942196/get-ssas-cube-last-process-time)

Please note that I have only read access to the underlying database, so I cannot create a table or column to hold the last date time in database.
If I create a dimension in DSV that would hold the last updated time, it loads 
on the first time but would fail if we try to use the slicer filters in excel.

What are the options without AMO ? Its an office PC, so I'm unable to download ASSP dlls. Can someone please suggest and if possible list down the step-by-step approach ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get SSAS cube last process time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19942196/get-ssas-cube-last-process-time)

Comment: Hi Aditya nope its not a duplicate of the link provided. The issue is I do not have write access to the underlying database and so cannot create an object (table or column) to hold the last updated time. If I do it in the dsv, the dimension only loads fine first time, but it fails when we use slicer filters in excel.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to add a new date dimension in Cube itself storing the timestamp value, which later can be fetched using MDX as last processed time ?